# GPS Daemon (gpsd) On RaspberryPi Claims NO FIX

Tags: gps, daemon, raspberry-pi2, gpsd

I've connected an adafruit ultimate gps v3 to a raspberry pi using a USB adaptor. The gps unit seems to have a fix because the led (on the gps unit) blinks at a slow rate (may be every 10 s). If I do `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0` I get NMEA data with location.

But when I install the gpsd, meaning:

```
sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

and run the daemon (cgps -s), it says no fix found and GPS times out. I tried to kill gpsd and run it again:

```
sudo killall gpsd

sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

but that didn't help. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: Please format your question using the given markups, e.g. precede 4 spaces for each line of code within a code block and surround commands in text with `backticks` ``

Answer (score 2):

`sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd`

change it to look like this

```
START_DAEMON="true"
GPSD_OPTIONS="/dev/ttyUSB0"
DEVICES=""
USBAUTO="true"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

then reboot. CGPS should work then.

Comment: You've crossed 'options' with 'devices'.  Options would bear flags, ( -b -G -n -N) e.g., `GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G -b"`